# List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject while autoforwarding objects using S2S

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce2salesforce

I am trying to implement S2S (Salesforce to salesforce) And I have written a code on Custom object called "ABC" to allow auto forwarding of records. After making the trigger active, I cannot manually create any records. Please help.

```
trigger SendABCToConnection on ABC__c(after insert,after update) {
        PartnerNetworkConnection conn = [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection  where ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted' and ConnectionName = 'XYZ'];
        List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection> recordConnectionToInsert  = new List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection>  ();
        for (ABC__c acc : Trigger.new){
            PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();

        newrecord.ConnectionId = conn.Id;
        newrecord.LocalRecordId = acc.id;  
        newrecord.SendClosedTasks = false;
        newrecord.SendOpenTasks = false;
        newrecord.SendEmails = false;
        recordConnectionToInsert.add(newrecord);
    }
    if (recordConnectionToInsert.size() > 0){
        System.debug('>>> Sharing ' + recordConnectionToInsert.size() + ' records');
        insert recordConnectionToInsert;
    }
 }
```

The error I am getting is :

> Apex trigger SendABCToConnection caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: SendABCToConnection: execution of
>   AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row
>   for assignment to SObject: Trigger.SendABCToConnection: line 2, column
>   1

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you have more than one PartnerNetworkConnection that matches the criteria you specified. You'll need to be *more specific* about which PartnerNetworkConnection you query for; I'd suggest querying by a specific account name `(e.g. WHERE Account.Name = 'Some Partner Account'`). Just make sure it's unique enough that you'll have one row when you do your query. You might also consider adding a try-catch block for a `QueryException`, since you only ever want one matching connection record, and report these errors to the user or an administrator.

```
PartnerNetworkConnection c;
try {
    c = [SELECT Id FROM PartnerNetworkConnection WHERE Account.Name = 'Some Partner Account'];
} catch(QueryException e) {
    // Report an error, then return
    return;
}
// Do your stuff with c;
```

Return, inside a trigger, has the effect of aborting early.

Comment: To supplement this excellent answer, the account name you use should come from some application configuration so if some genius changes the account.name value because the partner has undergone a name change you can recover without a code change/deploy cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 PartnerNetworkConnection conn = [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection  where ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted' and ConnectionName = 'XYZ'];
```

to this:

```
List<PartnerNetworkConnection> conns = [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection  where ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted' and ConnectionName = 'XYZ'];
```

And if you just want the first record use this:

```
conn[0]
```

Comment: So, choose one of the connections at random? That's hardly a good idea.

Comment: I assume the critera ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted' and ConnectionName = 'XYZ' is fair enough to provide the uniqueness and if it returns two records it means they are duplicates and choosing either one will not alter the output. But it makes more sense as you said to keep the system clean without such duplicates and have tailored criteria to return one result. But what if the system already has duplicates ?

Comment: The problem I foresee is that the connection name isn't unique but exists on two accounts, say "Acme" and "salesforce.com." Two completely different entities. Are you sure you'd want to take that chance?

Comment: My comment was generically on the system with duplicate entries. On this particular context it makes perfect sense and masking the exception with random pick as I did might not be a right approach. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA